# regex_match giving unexpected results

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I'm trying to write a recursive descent parser and am trying to search a match a regex within a string inputted by the user. I am trying to do the following to try to understand the `<regex>` library offered by C++11, but I'm getting unexpected results.

```
std::string expression = "2+2+2";
std::regex re("[-+*/()]");  
std::smatch m;

std::cout << "My expression is " << expression << std::endl;

if(std::regex_search(expression, re)) {
    std::cout << "Found a match!" << std::endl;
}

std::regex_match(expression, m, re);

std::cout << "matches:" << std::endl;
for (auto it = m.begin(); it!=m.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

So based on my regular expression, I expect it to output

```
Found a match!
matches:
+
+
```

However, the output I get is:

```
My expression is 2+2+2
Found a match!
matches:
```

I feel like I'm making a stupid mistake, but I can't seem to figure out why there's a discrepancy between the outputs.

Thanks,
erip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the `regex_iterator`, which solved the problem. Here's the working code:

```
std::regex re("[-+*/()]");  
std::smatch m;

std::cout << "My expression is " << expression << std::endl;

if(std::regex_search(expression, re)) {
    std::cout << "Found a match!" << std::endl;
}

try {
    std::sregex_iterator next(expression.begin(), expression.end(), re);
    std::sregex_iterator end;
    while (next != end) {
        std::smatch match = *next;
        std::cout << match.str() << "\n";
        next++;
    } 
} catch (std::regex_error& e) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got a few issues. First, let's look at some working code:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string expr = "2+2+2";
    std::regex re("[+\\-*/()]");

    const auto operators_begin = std::sregex_iterator(expr.begin(), expr.end(), re);
    const auto operators_end = std::sregex_iterator();

    std::cout << "Count: " << std::distance(operators_begin, operators_end) << "\n";

    for (auto i = operators_begin; i != operators_end; ++i) {
        std::smatch match = *i;
        std::cout << match.str() << "\n";
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
Count: 2
+
+
```

#### Issues with your code:

1. `regex_match()` returns false.
2. You don't have any capturing groups in the regular expression. So even if `regex_match()` returned true, it wouldn't capture anything.
3. The number of captures in a `regex_match` can be determined strictly by looking at the regular expression. So my re will capture exactly **one** group.
4. But we want to apply this regular expression on our string multiple times, because we want to find all of the matches. The tool for that is `regex_iterator`.
5. We also needed to escape the `-` in the regular expression. The minus has a special meaning within character classes.

Comment: I was actually just about to delete this question because I just found the `regex_iterator` and got my code to work. I will post the working answer in the question.

Comment: @erip: Feel free to actually write it as an answer! And then mark your new answer as accepted.